# Excel Macro Add Row, clear contents of specific columns

Tags: excel, vba

I've added a button to add row in a desired variable location and would like to keep the formulas existing in the new row, while eliminating other values.  Here's what I have right now:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim varUserInput As Variant
     varUserInput = InputBox("Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", _
      "What Row?")
     If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub

    RowNum = varUserInput
    Rows(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows(RowNum - 1 & ":" & RowNum - 1).Copy Range("A" & RowNum)
    Range(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).ClearContents

    End Sub
```

Instead of clearing all the contents of the new row as the last line of code commands, I'd like to only remove the contents in columns A:B and I:AG.

Thanks in advance,
Trevor

Answer (score 2):

Try using this in place of your last line:

```
Dim x As String

x = "A" & varUserInput & ":" & "B" & varUserInput
Range(x).ClearContents

x = "I" & varUserInput & ":" & "AG" & varUserInput
Range(x).ClearContents
```

Comment: This works perfectly - exactly what I needed. Thanks!